# Has color button gone on the latest Wygwam 3.0.2?

Tags: wygwam

I upgraded the Wygwam to the latest version on the latest EE installation and I seem to have lost the option to preset the the colour button. Seems to be a lot less options on this version. Is that correct or is it just hidden?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

We just released [Wygwam 3.1.2](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/changelog.html#wygwam-3-1-2), which brings back the text color buttons.